# $.getJSON will not load JSON Data

Tags: ajax, json

http://jsfiddle.net/ADvCJ/124/ works without the $.getJSON so that tells me Im having a problem with $.getJSON to work. I searched all over the place and cannot find solution to this issue. Please help!

Other thing I noticed it duplicates the four items from JSON how do I stop duplicating them?

code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("js/dataPokerPlayers.json", function(data) {
        $.each(pokerplayers, function(i, data){
            $(".tableData tbody").append("<tr><td>" + data.rank + "</td><td>" +     data.name + "</td><td>" + data.earnings + "</td><td>" + data.points + "</td><td>" +     data.totalearnings + "</td></tr>");
        });
    });
    });
```

Comment: Wrap your header row in `<thead>`. The code is finding 2 `<tbody>`s.

Comment: What errors do you see in the console for the getJSON part?

Comment: Thank you! That thead tag worked!

Comment: Paul Grime - it doesnt load the JSON data externally using $.getJSON

Comment: Add some logging in the getJSON callback (to make sure it's called) and show the errors. There must be some errors if it is failing.

Comment: Give me some example please...

Comment: `console.log(data)`. Check your browser for JS and/or network errors. Chrome and Firefox/Firebug consoles will show these errors.

Comment: Im showing syntax error js/dataPokerPlayers.json:1 on Firebug something to do on "var pokerplayers = [....", but it worked on jsfiddle? http://www.elitedeafpoker.com/dev/js/dataPokerPlayers.json

Comment: The contents of the URL you pasted isn't JSON. Remove the `var pokerplayers = ` from the start and the `;` from the end.

Comment: http://www.elitedeafpoker.com/dev/poker-players.html - worked! The table header disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there were a couple of changes required.

Firstly, the table needed a `<thead>` around the heading row.

```
<table class="tableData">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th width="250">Name</th>
            <th>Earnings</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Total Earnings</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

And secondly, the JSON URL wasn't really returning JSON; it was regular Javascript. `var pokerplayers =` needed to be removed from the start and `;` removed from the end of the content.